# C# Microsoft Sync Framework - MetadataStore on WebDAV server

Tags: c#, frameworks, synchronization, webdav

I'd like to implement a simple custom provider to do file synchronization between local files and a webdav server with the help of microsoft sync framework. The only example for a simple file sync provider that I've found is for local use: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/File-Sync-with-Simple-c497bf87/sourcecode?fileId=19013&pathId=1569663015

My problem is that I don't know how to adjust the MetadataStore in order to get saved on the remote server. Here are some changes that I've made to the code:

```
public MySimpleSyncFileProvider(Guid guidReplica, string rootFolder)
    {
        this._replicaId = new SyncId(guidReplica);
        this._rootFolder = "/";

        // Find location for metadata store 
        string metaDir = Path.Combine(_rootFolder, ".metadata");
        WebDAV.CreateDirectory(metaDir);
        WebDAV.SetAttributes(metaDir, WebDAVFileAttribute.isHidden);

        string metadataPath = Path.Combine(_rootFolder, ".metadata\\filemeta");

        // Open it 
        if (WebDAV.Exists(metadataPath))
            this._metadataStore = SqlMetadataStore.OpenStore(metadataPath); //TODO
        else
            this._metadataStore = SqlMetadataStore.CreateStore(metadataPath); //TODO
    }
```

I would have to change the "OpenStore" and "CreateStore" method, but I was not able to overwrite the SqlMetadataStore.

Do you have any suggestions? Or maybe an example how to implement a custom FileSyncProvider for webdav services?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that problem by simply storing the MetadataStore files on the local machine and using network shares.